# The e-mail message cannot be sent. Make sure the outgoing e-mail settings for the server are configured correctly

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, outgoing-mail

Please help .I have configured my outgoing email settings in sharepoint properly but still facing the same issue. Can any one help so it will be a pleasure.

Comment: add error message

Comment: hello sir ,  The error message in the workflow is "8/2/2017 4:23 PM Error 
"
The e-mail message cannot be sent. Make sure the outgoing e-mail settings for the server are configured correctly." @VindhyachalKumar